# How to consume npm package with es6 module via Webpack and 6to5?

Tags: commonjs, webpack, javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I want to use Immutable in my project (or any given npm package). I have `npm install`ed it, so it is in `node_modules`. Of course, it has CommonJS exports there. I, however, want to use es6 modules in my project.

I am using Webpack to compile it all together, with the 6to5-loader to deal with es6 module syntax.

In my source file, I say `import Immutable from 'immutable';` --- but this causes a problem because the es6 `import` is looking for an es6 `default` to have been exported, which isn't the case (for Immutable or probably almost any other npm package). The compiled code ends up looking like this: `var Immutable = require('immutable')["default"];` --- which of course throws an error, since there is no `default` property to find.

Can I consume the npm packages with es6 modules?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[Babel.js](https://babeljs.io) contributor here. You're looking for the following:

```
import * as Immutable from 'immutable';
// compiles to:
var Immutable = require('immutable');
```

[Interactive demo](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=import%20*%20as%20Immutable%20from%20'immutable'&experimental=true&playground=true&evaluate=true)

> Note: This is with either the `common` or `commonInterop` modules option. For others, see: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/modules/

Comment: So would you recommend that `import * as Immutable` syntax OVER using `commonInterop` and the `import Immutable` syntax I described? Is the `import * as Immutable` syntax what WILL work in the eventual "real-thing"?

Comment: `commonInterop` will likely become the [default](https://github.com/6to5/6to5/issues/242). I still recommend writing it this way because until your dependencies are written with es6 it's more correct (spec-wise) to write it as `import * as`.

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out. (The solution is tool-specific --- but es6 modules only exist now insofar as they are tool-enabled, so I think that's enough of an "answer".)

6to5's default module transpilation uses the `common` option, which results in the very problem I griped about above. But there is another option: `commonInterop` --- which must have been built to deal with exactly the situation I'm dealing with. See https://6to5.github.io/modules.html#common-interop

So three cheers for 6to5.