# topojson Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'feature' of undefined

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, ecmascript-6, topojson

### Background

- JavaScript is failing on a call to [topojson.feature(topology, object)](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#feature). That's the documentation for topojson-client which looks to have been added when topojson went to 2.x, but it's the same idea in 1.6.26 which is the version I'm on.
- Using webpack to build JS for production and webpack-dev-server for local development.
- It was working fine until fairly recently.

### Problem

> relevant_page.js:705 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'feature' of undefined

### Code

package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "topojson": "^1.6.26",
```

relevant_page.js:

```
import topojson from topojson;
...
function ready(data) {
  var topojsonStates = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.states).features;
```

### Troubleshooting

I set a breakpoint in the browser at the line that throws the error:

```
var topojsonStates = _topojson2.default.feature(us, us.objects.states).features;
```

and inspected these to see what was going on:

```
us: Object
  ...
  type: "Topology"

us.objects.states: Object
  ...
  type: "Topology"

_topojson2.default: undefined

_topojson2.feature(us, us.objects.states).features: Array[53]
```

The fact that `_topojson2.default` is undefined (and that `_topojson2.feature` works) gives me pause, but I'm not sure what's going on there. Any ideas?

### Notes / update

This is distinct from [how to consume an npm package with ES6 module via webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305954/how-to-consume-npm-package-with-es6-module-via-webpack-and-6to5), because there's no way to get to that question and answer if the main thing you have to go on is the Uncaught TypeError. Let me know if there's anything I should add to the question or answer to make it more useful and searchable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Came across a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/UDST/vizicities/issues/176) where someone reported the same thing, which was fixed in a [pull request](https://github.com/UDST/vizicities/pull/180/files) with the answer, which is to import topojson as a namespace:

```
import * as topojson from 'topojson';
```

which is how the [topojson-client documentation](https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md) instructs you to import it. I didn't realize it would be the same for 1.6.x. Sounds like this must have broken after switching to ES6.